# добавление .рth модели в tranformers

Tags: python, репозиторий

с помощью RVC я сделал голосовую модель, при попытке добавить её в код получается такая ошибка:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\Users\kostr\PycharmProjects\VikaVoiceTest\venv\Lib\site-packages\huggingface_hub\utils_errors.py",
> line 261, in hf_raise_for_status
> response.raise_for_status()   File "C:\Users\kostr\PycharmProjects\VikaVoiceTest\venv\Lib\site-packages\requests\models.py",
> line 1021, in raise_for_status
> raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self) requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 401 Client Error: Unauthorized for url:
> https://huggingface.co/G_2333333.pth/resolve/main/config.json
>
> The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\Users\kostr\PycharmProjects\VikaVoiceTest\venv\Lib\site-packages\transformers\utils\hub.py",
> line 430, in cached_file
> resolved_file = hf_hub_download(
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "C:\Users\kostr\PycharmProjects\VikaVoiceTest\venv\Lib\site-packages\huggingface_hub\utils_validators.py",
> line 118, in _inner_fn
> return fn(*args, **kwargs)
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "C:\Users\kostr\PycharmProjects\VikaVoiceTest\venv\Lib\site-packages\huggingface_hub\file_download.py",
> line 1346, in hf_hub_download
> raise head_call_error   File "C:\Users\kostr\PycharmProjects\VikaVoiceTest\venv\Lib\site-packages\huggingface_hub\file_download.py",
> line 1232, in hf_hub_download
> metadata = get_hf_file_metadata(
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "C:\Users\kostr\PycharmProjects\VikaVoiceTest\venv\Lib\site-packages\huggingface_hub\utils_validators.py",
> line 118, in _inner_fn
> return fn(*args, **kwargs)
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "C:\Users\kostr\PycharmProjects\VikaVoiceTest\venv\Lib\site-packages\huggingface_hub\file_download.py",
> line 1608, in get_hf_file_metadata
> hf_raise_for_status(r)   File "C:\Users\kostr\PycharmProjects\VikaVoiceTest\venv\Lib\site-packages\huggingface_hub\utils_errors.py",
> line 293, in hf_raise_for_status
> raise RepositoryNotFoundError(message, response) from e huggingface_hub.utils._errors.RepositoryNotFoundError: 401 Client
> Error. (Request ID:
> Root=1-6552e8bd-7d02c52b231d724e738e5549;b946dc78-c494-4f01-8882-d38b8c4c62a4)
>
> Repository Not Found for url:
> https://huggingface.co/G_2333333.pth/resolve/main/config.json. Please
> make sure you specified the correct `repo_id` and `repo_type`. If you
> are trying to access a private or gated repo, make sure you are
> authenticated. Invalid username or password.
>
> The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\Users\kostr\PycharmProjects\VikaVoiceTest\voice.py", line 8, in
>
> model = T5ForConditionalGeneration.from_pretrained(model_path)
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File
> "C:\Users\kostr\PycharmProjects\VikaVoiceTest\venv\Lib\site-packages\transformers\modeling_utils.py",
> line 2600, in from_pretrained
> resolved_config_file = cached_file(
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "C:\Users\kostr\PycharmProjects\VikaVoiceTest\venv\Lib\site-packages\transformers\utils\hub.py",
> line 451, in cached_file
> raise EnvironmentError( OSError: G_2333333.pth is not a local folder and is not a valid model identifier listed on
> 'https://huggingface.co/models' If this is a private repository, make
> sure to pass a token having permission to this repo either by logging
> in with `huggingface-cli login` or by passing `token=<your_token>`

код я взял вот с этого сайта: https://ru.anyquestion.info/a/shag-za-shagom-sintez-golosa-po-tekstu-s-pomoschyu-configjson-i-g-2333333pth-v-python

я так понимаю, что мне надо как-то добавить модель в репозиторий hugginface, но можно ли как-то без этого обойтись?

Comment: "G_2333333.pth is not a local folder and is not a valid model identifier" - судя по этой ошибке вы можете указать локальную папку с моделью, просто скрипт не нашёл такую локальную папку, поэтому полез в репозиторий искать.